# Tagging: winterraum vs winter-room

Tags: discussion, tags

The question [Are all Alpine winterraums just for emergency?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/13977/3602) has been tagged with [winterraum](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winterraum). It is the first question with this tag and I was wondering whether this is a term used in English?
If it is not, [winter-room](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter-room) would probably be better suited.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware we use Winterraum in English as well - we don't translate it. Probably because we don't really have anything similar here - we have bothies (which I think are like refugio) but no separate room.

So I'm fine with it being tagged [winterraum](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winterraum).

Comment: I suspected this but wasn't sure as a wiki article to winterroom was added to the question. It isn't the only German word in English either. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I'm the one who put in that wikipedia link in to winter room, because I had never heard of one and wanted to add a reference. When I searched for winterraum,  wikipedia directed it to winter room, with winterraum as an alternate term. Wikipedia does have a [winterraum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winterraum) page but it's in German. Everything else on the front Google search page is also in German.

Comment: In the interest of serving the whole community, would it make sense to create winter-room as a synonym so that it would automatically switch to winterraum when used?